# problems using grep -f

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

I have 'fileA' which is a list of patterns I want to extract from 'file B':

fileA:

```
chr6    60  
chr6    12691   
chr6    12701
```

fileB - sorry it curls, there should be up to 13 columns per record (records start with chr6):

```
chr6    60  81.04   C   A   intergenic_region   MODIFIER                            
chr6    12691   148.33  C   G   synonymous_variant  LOW SILENT  acC/acG T29 Medtr6g003930   Medtr6g003930.1 1   WARNING_TRANSCRIPT_INCOMPLETE)
chr6    12691   148.33  C   G   upstream_gene_variant   MODIFIER        889     Medtr6g003930   Medtr6g003930.2     
chr6    12697   306.25  G   A   upstream_gene_variant   MODIFIER        883     Medtr6g003930   Medtr6g003930.2     
chr6    12701   848.07  C   A   synonymous_variant  LOW SILENT  Cgg/Agg R33 Medtr6g003930   Medtr6g003930.1 1   WARNING_TRANSCRIPT_INCOMPLETE)
chr6    12706   35.87   G   A   synonymous_variant  LOW SILENT  ccG/ccA P34 Medtr6g003930   Medtr6g003930.1 1   WARNING_TRANSCRIPT_INCOMPLETE)
chr6    12888   900.07  C   A   synonymous_variant  LOW SILENT  Cgg/Agg R33 Medtr6g003930   Medtr6g003930.1 1   WARNING_TRANSCRIPT_INCOMPLETE)
```

I have tried :
**grep -f fileA fileB > t1**  AND **grep -Ff fileA fileB > t2**

In both cases, my output is identical to fileB (meaning grep didnt subset anything). However, **grep '12691' > t3** works (extracts the 2 lines from fileB which have the string). But this wont help me on files with thousands of records.

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong?

ps.I dont know if this helps, but 
using the same commands on 'only text' files, DOES work.

Comment: since `chr6` is just common, why not remove them from fileA?

Comment: `grep -Ff fileA fileB` does work for me for given samples on `(GNU grep) 2.25`.. see if you have empty line in `fileA`

Comment: it's difficult to see since it seems that there are tabs & spaces mixed. Could you try with fileA containing lines like `chr6\s+60` and adding the `-P` option?

Comment: Hi Sundeep I did remove chr6 but the same happened, also I dont think there are any empty lines in fileA. Is there a way you could show me the output you get from the same files?

Comment: Hi Jean-François, I am not sure I understand what you propose?

Comment: @JazFlo  it gave me four lines.. also I noticed there are extra spaces at end of lines in `fileA` but still matched properly... so not sure why it doesn't work for you.. when you removed `chr6` did you also remove every other space characters?